# c# detect if a key is pressed in background

Tags: c#, c

I make an program that will kill a process when I press Ctrl + NumPad0 , but the process will get killed when I'm on the program and i want to kill the prcoess if I'm playing a games for example.
Anyone know how to do?

Sorry for the bad grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create a keyboard hook. see [SetWindowsHookEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: What I would suggest.

Comment: Maybe that could also work:
Create a batch file which terminates the desired process using taskkill.exe. Place a shortcut to this batch file on the desktop and set the shortcut key in the file properties.

Comment: ok thanks but i can't understand how hook work soo can you link a tutorial??

Comment: yes it's five hours i'm trying to do hook -.-

Comment: there are ready to use .net libraries for this.
google for the following keywords: setwindowshookex c# site:codeproject.com